# Is it possible to reinstall and activate Win 8 for other account?

Tags: windows, windows-8, reinstall, windows-activation

This might be a stupid question but I couldn't find answer anywhere and I want to be sure before I do something irreversible. I'm selling my computer with Windows 8 which I have bought and activated. I'm planning to erase everything with Windows' own [Remove everything and reinstall Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) tool. After doing this, can I activate Windows 8 again with different Windows account or is the activation somehow tied to my Windows account? The hardware is still the same as when I actived Windows 8 on this computer. The license is "Windows 8 for OEM software".

Comment: The license is not connected to your Microsoft Account.  Be sure you do a Reset not Refresh otherwise your existing user accounts won't be deleted.  The license itself is locked to that computer you won't be able to use it on another machine you own.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved my "old PC Hard disk" (with windows 8.1 on it) to my new PC which has all  new hardware, then booted from this same hard disk, Windows requested to reactivate windows. I have used "activate by telephone calling Microsoft automated answer machine" followed instruction and succeeded to reactivate Windows.
How to Reactivate in Windows 8.1: Control Panel (Control Panel Items) -> System    then press Activate/or Change product key. Enter your old PC key no, and if not accepted, the pannel will direct you Re-Enter different Key/ or Activate by Telephone. Proceed from there. Good luck